# Intel Joule 570x Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit How to enable /dev/ttyS2?

Tags: 16.04, drivers

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 64-bit LTS into an Intel Joule 570x.  It works and boots up reliably from an SDHC card.

The Joule has an FTDI USB-to-Serial chip on the expansion board and it's used during installs by various Linux installers.  The schematic shows it as connected to UART2 on the Joule Compute module.

It's there.  I'd like to use it.  I've tried a variety of things to gain access to it and, well, nothing I've tried (including some noob-level searching around the net) has produced a solution.

(Running a search with "Joule serial" produces a large number of hits on getting an OS installed.  I'm trying to go the other way, and establish a connection to the UART side of the FTDI chip).

`setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0-3]` reports:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port 0x03F8, IRQ: 4  
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port 0x02F8, IRQ: 3  
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port 0x03e8, IRQ: 4  
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port 0x02F8, IRQ: 3
```

There are quite a few options as to what the UART type can be set to.. and I've tried most of them.  Note: I didn't find setserial in the installation and so installed it using apt-get.  Clean install.

```
  struct termios term;
  int fd = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR);  // always > 0.
  int i = tcgetattr(fd, &term);
```

I run this as root, with a bash shell.  It fails with i = -1.  `perror()` outputs "Input/output error".

=============
putty fails: can't initialize port.
minicom: doesn't know any better, no errors, no output either.

Suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 20, 2017, there is NO support in 16.04.1 LTS Desktop for Intel Joule 570x UART0-2, I2C0-1, or SPI0-1.  UART2 is active in Core Beta 4.  In order to access UART2 in Core, you'll need to disable the system's serial-console getty.

Comment: Yes... seems to be a lot missing from this port of Ubuntu.  16.04.1 LTS Desktop (Developer?) is missing access to hardware.  Thanks.